# Take Longitude/Latitude and get UTC Offset in Perl

Tags: perl, datetime, geolocation, timezone

I'm trying to localize times that are in UTC when the only thing I know about the destination time is the longitude and latitude. I've come up with something that works, but feels kludgy:

```
# We need to get localized time for display purposes.
state $moduleGeoLocation = require Geo::Location::TimeZone;
my $gltzobj = Geo::Location::TimeZone->new();
my $tzName = $gltzobj->lookup( lon => $params->{'longitude'}, lat => $params->{'latitude'} );
say "TimeZone: " . $tzName;
```

So far so good. Here's where the kludge comes in. I'm parsing a time using Time::Piece's `strptime` but I don't have a GMT offset for the timezone, so after I parse the UTC time in Time::Piece, I'm sending it over to DateTime to do the time zone calculation. It seems rather clunky to be using both DateTime and Time::Piece:

```
# Get TimeZoneOffset.
state $moduleDateTime = require DateTime;
state $moduleDateTimeTimeZone = require DateTime::TimeZone;
my $timeZone = DateTime::TimeZone->new( 'name' => $tzName );

my $timePiece = Time::Piece->strptime($hour->{'time'}, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ');
my $time = DateTime->from_epoch( 'epoch' => $timePiece->epoch, 'time_zone' => $timeZone );
```

Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm doing? I'm aiming for the fastest possible way to get to the result of a localized time.

Comment: There's [DateTime::Format::Strptime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Strptime), so no need for `Time::Piece`.  Is that it?

Comment: Also, since Geo::Location::TimeZone returns time zones of the form `Etc/GMT+X`, it means Daylight-Saving Time won't be observed.

Comment: @ikegami is there another module that you'd recommend instead that does as you say? That is pretty awful for your timezone. Although, I'm getting named zones out of G::L::TZ, not GMT+X. E.g. It is giving me "America/Chicago" for (CST/CDT), which should work with daylight savings time...

Comment: Finding time-zones for lon,lat with accuracy isn't simple. Other than the library used here, there is a good-looking list of tools in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16086964/4653379) (not Perl but many are web services). I tried [google API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/overview), which is really simple to use and I presume accurate. But it requires one to get an [API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/get-api-key) ...

Comment: Have a look at my project [here](https://github.com/simbabque/ingress-fs-finder/blob/master/bin/parse.pl), I'm doing roughly the same thing. I've found that Geo::Location::TimeZone is not very accurate. My input is all over the world, usually larger cities, and it often misses a few. So I only use that as a fallback now.

Comment: @simbabque Perfect. Thank. I followed your lead and it really seems to be working better. GeoNames could almost replace my queries to OpenStreetMap, too, in addition to figuring out Time Zones although OSM seems to be a little more accurate in converting text strings to the most logical place possible, so I'm still querying OSM and then passing long/lat to the GeoNames API. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question boils down to the following:

> How do I create a DateTime object from a timestamp using the `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S` format. I have the appropriate time zone as a DateTime::TimeZone object.

To parse a date-time into a DateTime, one should first look for an appropriate DateTime::Format:: module.

[DateTime::Format::Strptime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Strptime) would be the most similar to your current attempt.

```perl
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );
 
my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern   => '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S',
   strict    => 1,
   time_zone => $tz,
   on_error  => 'croak',
);

my $dt = $format->parse_datetime($ts);
```

You could also use [DateTime::Format::ISO8601](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::ISO8601), although you couldn't use it as a validator since it doesn't accept only the stated format.

```perl
use DateTime::Format::ISO8601 qw( );
 
( my $dt = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->parse_datetime($ts) )
   ->set_time_zone('floating')
   ->set_time_zone($tz);
```

Given that the latter solution overrides any explicitly-provided time zone, I'd use the first solution for clarity.

Comment: Thanks! That works great. I should have gone with DateTime to begin with -- I decided to try using Time::Piece not realizing I'd be stuck when it came to timezones.

Comment: TZ conversions can be done using T::P. But I consider T::P to be a rather poor module.

Comment: As @ikegami says, the conversions ar possible in Time::Piece, but it's very, very fragile. You have to get the stars to align just right. I just did this for a particular project that's stuck with core Perl, and that was not fun.

Comment: @brian d foy, I'm surprise at that. Well, I'm surprised if it was a Linux system. That would imply that time zones are fragile for all programs using the C library, which is basically all of them.

Comment: Good to know. I thought I was missing out on something not trying T::P, but it doesn't sound like it.

Comment: It's more about what every different person puts in their TZ, which could be anything they copied off the internet.

Comment: @brian d foy, ah, sure. But that doesn't speak to the fragility of time zone conversion, but the difficulty of obtaining the user's time zone. Wouldn't that problem exist just as much for DateTime as Time::Piece?

Comment: No idea there. Time::Piece relies on the system to provide various things. I thought DateTime had it's own timezone database.

Comment: @briandfoy, It does. It uses a fresh copy of the tz database rather than using the C library. But DateTime still uses the TZ env var.

Comment: @briandfoy, Now, if you mean that people have bad data in their actual local time zone database, I heard of such problems, but I think that's a problem of the past (on Linux)